# Paginator Class based views not working in DJANGO

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-class-based-views, paginator

I am not sure why the paginator is not working. It does show at the bottom of the page but it does not apply to the list objects from "Entity" table.

Is there something i am doing wrong in my html or views?

models.py

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    entity_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Entities"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.entity_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('snippets:password', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py

```
class EntityListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    template_name = 'snippets/list.html'

    def get(self, request):

        queryset = Entity.objects.filter(owner=request.user)

        paging = queryset

        paginator = Paginator(paging, 3) 

        page = request.GET.get('page')

        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)

        return render(request, self.template_name, context={
                                                'entities':queryset,
                                                'page_obj':page_obj
                                                })
```

html.py

```
{% for entity in entities %}

        <a href='{% url "snippets:password" entity.pk %}'>{{ entity.entity_name }}</br></br></br></a>

      {% endfor %}


      <div class="pagination">
          <span class="step-links">
              {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                  <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
                  <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
              {% endif %}

              <span class="current">
                  Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
              </span>

              {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                  <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                  <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
              {% endif %}
          </span>
      </div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think should be like this

`return render(request, self.template_name, context={'entities':page_obj,'page_obj':page_obj})`

also i think will be more simple like this:

```
class EntityListView(ListView):
  model = Entity
  context_object_name = 'entities'
  paginate_by = 3
```

Comment: Actually `entities` should be `page_obj.object_list`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you.The goal was also to return the list of objects from Entity table per user so the different user cannot get access to the same list of items (those that i have not created)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you pass the `queryset` as `entities` to your renderer, not the [**`page_obj.object_list`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Page.object_list), which is a collection of elements to render.

But you are doing *too much* yourself here. In fact a [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) is defined to remove all that boilerplate code for you, otherwise the `ListView` would be quite useless:

```
class EntityListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Entity
    template_name = 'snippets/list.html'
    context_object_name = 'entities'
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Django will automatically paginate the result of [**`get_queryset`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) and associate it with the [**`context_object_name`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.context_object_name) (here `'entities'`).

By specifying the [**`model = Entity`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.model), we can easily reuse the above model with a different model.

Comment: The error was ```TypeError: get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'```. with the code you provided above.

Comment: @CurtisBanks: but you called `get_queryset` yourself? Why? Django's `ListView` *implements* `.get(..)` itself: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#get that is actually the *entire* point of a `ListView`. You should not do (most) of the *how*, but more the *what*.

Comment: I used ```queryset``` initially to assign a queryset to a variable, not as a method.

Comment: @CurtisBanks: but the point of a `ListView` is, as said before, that you do not need to write this `queryset = ...`, `paginator = ...` and `render(...)`, yourself. Django already implemented this for you, the only thing that you sometimes need to do is override `get_queryset`, `get_context_data`, etc. Here you only need to override, the `get_queryset`. Nothing else. Take a look at the `.get(..)` implementation. Django implemented logic to paginate, and render the template.